# 2000s sci-fi cartoon show with a group of friends sucked into a console/TV to another dimension

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I only have vague memories of this show but am for some reason determined to find it.

From what I can remember it was about a group of friends getting sucked into a game console/TV and going on adventures in another dimension that seemed to be very rocky.

I'm sure I remember a giant robot/mech at one point. It was most likely aired on Cartoon Network/Boomerang/Nickelodeon but I can't be sure.

It may have only been a miniseries or even just a single animated film. It could even be just a single episode from a series.

I've check a bunch of lists on Wikipedia and can't seem to find it.

If it helps, I'm from the UK, so it could have been a show only available here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!!!

It's called *[Da Boom Crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Boom_Crew)*.

> After four young foster children create a video game about heroes attempting to defeat space alien terrorists in various planets, suddenly a portal appears and transports them into a dimension that is really similar to their game. This show also details their adventures in this parallel world as they embark on a quest to find their missing game cartridges they call “Boom Carts” and conquer the sadistic extraterrestrial emperor Zorch before he takes control of this galaxy.

### Opening

Comment: You will be able to accept your answer in about 45 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. So, how did you find it? How does it match?

Comment: I've added some information, but it would probably be good if you provided your own details.